# How to convert Char[] into a Vector

Tags: java, arrays, vector, char, jtable

I want to display the contents of a char[] in a Jtable. Apparently, Java cannot construct Jtables with char. Since I cannot do this directly, I am trying to convert the `char[]` into a vector for the table. I have tried the following approach unsuccessfully.

```
char[] X;

Vector<String> vx = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(x));
```

Comment: After answering, I noticed you're trying to make a `Vector<String>` rather than a `Vector<Character>`. Can you clarify? If I start with `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` should the answer be `["a", "b", "c"]` or `["abc"]`?

Comment: The answer should be ["a", "b", "c"]. I want to display each element in the char[] as its own column in the Jtable.

Comment: @user5621297 Ok, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ArrayList` rather than `Vector`. There is no simple way to convert though. One way is

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (char a : x)
    list.add(String.valueOf(a));
```

`Arrays.asList` works for arrays of object references, not arrays of primitives like `char`.

If you are using Java 8, another way is

```
List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, x.length)
                             .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(x[i]))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried this and got "The type List is not generic and cannot be parameterized with arguments <character>"

Comment: Check your `import`. It should be `import java.util.List`.

Comment: Thank you pointing helping with this. I was missing the import and that fixed the first error message. I tried your revised first approach and the only error I am getting is "Can only iterate over an array or instance of java.lang.iterable." Should I replace "a" with a certain value?

Comment: I thought you said `x` was a `char[]`? You can definitely iterate over a `char[]`. I think you need to include all your code, because it is very unclear to me why just pasting this code into yours doesn't work.

Comment: You are correct. I found the error and the code is working now. This is my first time using Java so it has been a learning experience. I had instanced x as "public char x." The error went away when I changed this to "public char[] x". I guess this mistake prevented the values generated in x from being shared with your solution.

Comment: @user5621297 Glad I could help. The syntax `for ( something a : x)` only works if `x` is an array, or if `x` implements `Iterable` (this usually means it is a `List` or a `Set`). If `x` is anything else, you'll get a compile error.